# Is this errormessage (uses or overrides a deprecated API) related to my NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, android

I am facing a warning like this one:

```
... uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details does this warning
```

This is my first time to see it. I face some null issues in my app so i wonder if this warning has a relation with my issues.

This is my adapter that I face the warning in 
but the logcat tells me that i face nulls in other pages too so are all connected to this warning or not. thanks in advance

````
```
package com.example.quiz.Adabter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.quiz.Common.Common;
import com.example.quiz.Model.CurrentQuestion;
import com.example.quiz.R;

import java.util.List;

public class ResultGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultGridAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<CurrentQuestion> currentQuestionList;

    public ResultGridAdapter(Context context, List<CurrentQuestion> currentQuestionList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.currentQuestionList = currentQuestionList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_result_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        Drawable img;

        myViewHolder.btn_question.setText(new StringBuilder("Question").append(currentQuestionList.get(i)
                .getQuestionIndex() + 1));
        if (currentQuestionList.get(i).getType() == Common.ANSWER_TYPE.RIGHT_ANSWER) {
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff99cc00"));
            img = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_white_24dp);
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, img);
        } else if (currentQuestionList.get(i).getType() == Common.ANSWER_TYPE.WRONG_ANSWER) {
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffcc0000"));
            img = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_24dp);
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, img);
        } else {
            img = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp);
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, img);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return currentQuestionList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button btn_question;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            btn_question = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_question);
            btn_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                            .sendBroadcast(new Intent(Common.KEY_BACK_FROM_RESULT).putExtra(Common.KEY_BACK_FROM_RESULT
                                    , currentQuestionList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getQuestionIndex()));
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
````

Comment: What excatlly is the issue you have? Any stack-trace?

Comment: Generally deprecated APIs aren't related to NullPointerException, but you'd at least post your log messages and the line where the error is noticed